# Bookmark current song

Tags: music

I don't know if I need an app for this or can I do it with the given music app. I've downloaded a bunch of lectures and they're all in one album.
 Sometimes I want to listen to music, but when I do, I lose my place in the lecture album. Is there a way to bookmark or save the current song/position so I can quickly switch back? Preferably free.

Comment: You'll probably need to find a music application which supports podcast/audiobooks, and then set your lectures as one of those.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [Audiobook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.stohelit.audiobookplayer) variant of MortPlayer. I believe it ought to suit your needs. Also - it's free.

One of its features is particularly useful:

> List of 10 most recent events for each track (where did you press play, stop, got interrupted by a call, activate the sleep timer, ...)